# How to check two fields in a document while registering in Express.js , mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have designed schema for user and registration time i am checking the email (unique)already exist or not .if already registered i am throwing  mes 'email address is already in use'. this is working fine now i want to check two fields email and mobilenumber . how can i achieve this ?? help me out

below is my full user schema design

```
    'use strict';

    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var UserSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        mobilenumber : String,
        email: {
            type: String,

        },
        hashedPassword: String,
        provider: String,
        salt: String,
    });

    /**
     * Virtuals
     */
    UserSchema
      .virtual('password')
      .set(function(password) {
        this._password = password;
        this.salt = this.makeSalt();
        this.hashedPassword = this.encryptPassword(password);
      })
      .get(function() {
        return this._password;
      });

    // Public profile information
    UserSchema
      .virtual('profile')
      .get(function() {
        return {
          'name': this.name,
          'role': this.role
        };
      });

    // Non-sensitive info we'll be putting in the token
    UserSchema
      .virtual('token')
      .get(function() {
        return {
          '_id': this._id,
          'role': this.role
        };
      });

    /**
     * Validations
     */

    // Validate empty email
    UserSchema
      .path('email')
      .validate(function(email) {
        if (authTypes.indexOf(this.provider) !== -1) return true;
        return email.length;
      }, 'Email cannot be blank');

    // Validate empty password
    UserSchema
      .path('hashedPassword')
      .validate(function(hashedPassword) {
        if (authTypes.indexOf(this.provider) !== -1) return true;
        return hashedPassword.length;
      }, 'Password cannot be blank');

    // Validate email is not taken
    UserSchema
        .path('email')
        .validate(function(value, respond) {
            var self = this;
            this.constructor.findOne({
                email: value
            }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (user) {
                    if (self.id === user.id) return respond(true);
                    return respond(false);
                }
                respond(true);
            });
        }, 'email address is already in use.');

    var validatePresenceOf = function(value) {
        return value && value.length;
    };


/**
 * Pre-save hook
 */
UserSchema
  .pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!this.isNew) return next();

    if (!validatePresenceOf(this.hashedPassword) && authTypes.indexOf(this.provider) === -1)
      next(new Error('Invalid password'));
    else
      next();
  });

/**
 * Methods
 */
UserSchema.methods = {
  /**
   * Authenticate - check if the passwords are the same
   *
   * @param {String} plainText
   * @return {Boolean}
   * @api public
   */
  authenticate: function(plainText) {
    return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashedPassword;
  },

  /**
   * Make salt
   *
   * @return {String}
   * @api public
   */
  makeSalt: function() {
    return crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
  },

  /**
   * Encrypt password
   *
   * @param {String} password
   * @return {String}
   * @api public
   */
  encryptPassword: function(password) {
    if (!password || !this.salt) return '';
    var salt = new Buffer(this.salt, 'base64');
    return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
  }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

in registration time if user entered already  registered email or mobilenumber code should throw the error like 'email address is already in use' or 'mobilenumber is already in use' .if both or matched 'email and mobilenumber alreay in use' help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of validating field you should create a method to check for both the email and mobileNumber. Check code below:

```
UserSchema.statics.validateMobileAndEmail= function (email, mobileNumber, cb) {
  return this.find({email: email, mobileNumber: mobileNumber}).exec(function(err, user){
    if(err) return cb(err);

    if(user.email === email && user.mobileNumber === mobileNumber){
       return cb(null, 'email and mobilenumber already exists');
    } else if(user.email === email ){
       return cb(null, 'email already exists');
    } else if(user.mobileNumber === mobileNumber){
       return cb(null, ' mobilenumber already exists');
    } 
    return cb();
 })
}
```

and before creating record call it with the email and mobileNumber.

```
UserSchema.validateMobileAndEmail(email, mobileNumber, function(err, msg){
   if(err){ return res.json({error:'internal server error'});}
   else if(msg) {return res.json({error: msg});}
   else{
      // register user code
   }

})
```

ex.

```
UserSchema.validateMobileAndEmail('email@email.com', '2222222222', function(err, msg){
       if(err){ return res.json({error:'internal server error'});}
       else if(msg) {return res.json({error: msg});}
       else{
          // register user code
       }

    })
```

Comment: what i have to write inside this function 'UserSchema.validateMobileAndEmail'

Comment: i am getting error   UserSchema.validateMobileAndEmail(email, mobileNumber, function(err, msg){
                                  ^

ReferenceError: email is not defined

Comment: pass these values when like a method call.

Comment: i did't not get sir . u mean req.body.email and req.body.mobilenumber i need to pass thr right?

Comment: UserSchema.validateMobileAndEmail('sujitha@gmail.com', '9687567895', function(err, msg){
           ^

TypeError: UserSchema.validateMobileAndEmail is not a function ...i am getting error like this

Comment: refer to this link for static methods. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html and update your code in question. let me check how you are implementing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125967/discussion-between-ko001-and-sachin).

Answer (score 0):

You can get validation on both fields, but mongoose will show you error of the first failed validation, it will not show both validation error together.

If both email and  mobile exists, it will show you email address is already in use. because mongoose will stop when first validation failed.

If thats fine with you just add same validation for mobile below the email validation.

```
UserSchema
    .path('mobilenumber')
    .validate(function(value, respond) {
        var self = this;
        this.constructor.findOne({
            mobilenumber : value
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (user) {
                if (self.id === user.id) return respond(true);
                return respond(false);
            }
            respond(true);
        });
    }, 'mobile is already in use.');
```

Other wise you can put custom validation inside your code.